# Does it still make sense to cache OpenGL states?

Tags: opengl

There used to be a time when people said that 'managing' the OpenGL states was useful (just saw an article on it from 2001). Like this (C++):

```
void CStateManager::setCulling(bool enabled)
{
  if (m_culling != enabled)
  {
    m_culling = enabled;
    if (m_culling)
      glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    else
      glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  }
}
```

I can see that this might be still useful in a situation where the OpenGL server is not on the same place as the OpenGL client. But that certainly isn't the case in my 'game'-engine, so let's assume the OpenGL client is always on the same machine as the OpenGL server.

Is it still (it's 2017 now) worth it to have all this checking-code take up cycles instead of just always calling the driver?

One could say that I should profile it myself, but I don't think the results will matter because there are so much different graphics adapters, drivers, CPU's, OS's out there that my personal test can not be representative enough.

EDIT: And how about things like bound buffers, framebuffers, textures, ...

Comment: That depends. If you are doing a lot of unnecessary calls, then yes, you'll benefit from it. But in the end it will bowl down to "measure it". That's also the only thing anyone else could do.

Comment: for buffers you could also use Direct State Access way ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it still (it's 2017 now) worth it to have all this checking-code take up cycles instead of just always calling the driver?

You say that as though it *ever were* "worth it". It wasn't, and it still isn't. At least, not in *general*.

State caching is useful in the cases where it was before: when you don't have direct control over what's going on.

For example, if you're writing a game engine, you have firm knowledge over what rendering operations you intend to do, and when you intend to do them. You know that all of your meshes are going to use face culling, and you make your artists/tool pipeline deal with that accordingly. You might turn off face culling for GUI rendering or something like that, but those would be specific cases.

By contrast, if you're writing a generalized rendering system, where the user has near total control over the nature of meshes, state caching might help. If your code is being told which meshes use face culling and which do not, then you have no control over that sort of thing. And since the higher-level code/data isn't able to talk to OpenGL directly, you can do some state caching to smooth things over.

So if you're in control of how things get rendered, if you control the broad nature of your data and the way it gets drawn, then you don't need a cache. Your code does that job adequately. And in good data-driven designs, you can order the rendering of the data so that you still don't need a cache. You only need one in a completely free-wheeling system, where the outside world has near-total control over all state and has little regard for the performance impact of its state changes.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you. Accepted the answer as I think you are completely right.